# Embedding TableView in TableViewController into another view

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I would like to customize content of table view controller(add some buttons, etc.) but root view for that is table view. Is it a way to embed it into another view and add controls on it?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use **Container View**.

In the storyboard create another view controller that you would use to host those controls. Then drag in  **Container View** from the *Object Library* (normally the last item in the list) and place it where you want the table view to appear (which could be the whole screen). Doing this, the **Container View** will create another view controller. Simply delete that and `ctrl` drag from the **Container View** to your table view controller and select **embed** segue.

By doing this, you would not have to change anything in your current table view controller if it doesn't depend on other view controllers to give it data in order for it to work. If it does, however, you could assign the segue identifier to the **embed** segue, implement `prepareForSegue:sender:` and do whatever you would normally do with other segues.

Answer (score 1):

You simply add TableView as a subview of a uiviewcontroller. Remember to call for delegates. Normally i don't use storyboards, but if you do it programmatically you can do like this:

On .h file:

```
@interface EmbeddedTableView : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
```

And on .m file simply create your tableView by adding it as subview of viewcontroller.

You can look at this for example: [How to set up UITableView within a UIViewController created on a .xib file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11465579/how-to-set-up-uitableview-within-a-uiviewcontroller-created-on-a-xib-file)