# Cut off UITableViewController when embedded into a Container in a UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift

In order for to customize a table view and add some additional controls to it, I've embedded a UTTableViewController into a Container View and placed that container View into a UIViewController.

I've followed the instructions I found here: Embedding TableView in TableViewController into another view
[image]

The issue is that the right side of the table view with Detail labels is getting cut off, I've tried various clipping settings and fit options in Storyboard, but can't seem to guess which one to use or perhaps there is another approach? Looking for a suggestion.

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Did you check the TableView constraint ??  Maybe lose some constraint

Comment: well.. it's a UITableViewController embedded in a Container View. Not sure how/if I can set up constraints in such case? I would think that Container View would fit it's subviews automatically by default, but no luck.. somehow the right margin is getting clipped.

Comment: If you add constraint with related to margin then this may happen.

Comment: see this ....http://stackoverflow.com/q/25807545/4030971

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out myself.

I had to control-drag from the Container View to the parent View Controller to defined constraints for it. I found the video that helped:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AaCfwqzH9SQ